# Splinter: Getting pieces of XPATH text that aren't unique elements

Tags: python, html, xpath, splinter

How do I get the text of the first, underline, and last part of the `question` and store it into a variable, using Splinter?

See the HTML at the bottom. I want to make the following variables have the following values:

```
first_part = "Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the"
second_part = "_______"
third_part = "! Oh what fun it is to ride in one-horse open sleigh!"
```

I went [here](http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/), used the XPATHs

```
//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/text()[1] #this is first_part
//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/span      #this is second_part
//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/text()[2] #this is third_part
```

and applied them to the below HTML. They returned the wanted values in the test, but for my program, Splinter seems to reject them:

```
first_part = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath = '//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/text()[1]').text
second_part = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath = '//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/span').text
third_part = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath = '//*[@id="question_container"]/div[1]/span/text()[2]').text

print first_part
print second_part
print third_part

--------------    OUTPUT     -------------

[]
[]
[]
```

**What am I doing wrong, why is it wrong, and how should I change my code?**

The referred-to HTML (which was slightly edited to 'Jingle Bells' to better convey the problem) was retrieved  using the `browser.html` feature of Splinter:

```
<div id="question_container" style="display: block;">
<div class="question_wrap">

<span class="question">Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the
<span class="underline" style="display: none;">_______</span>
<input type="text" name="vocab_answer" class="answer" id="vocab_answer"></input>
! Oh what fun it is to ride in one-horse open sleigh!</span>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xpath` passed to the `find_by_xpath()` method *has to point/result to an element*, not a text node.

One option would be to find the outer `span`, get it's `html` and feed it to [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

element = browser.find_by_xpath(xpath='//div[@id="question_container"]//span[@class="question"]')

root = fromstring(element.html)
first_part = root.xpath('./text()[1]')[0]
second_part = root.xpath('./span/text()')[0]
third_part = root.xpath('./text()[last()]')[0]

print first_part, second_part, third_part
```

Prints:

```
Jingle bells, jingle bells, jingle all the
_______ 
! Oh what fun it is to ride in one-horse open sleigh!
```

Comment: What do I use instead of `find_by_xpath()`? I can't find another relevant method in Splinter's documentation.

Comment: @Princee you should find the `span` with `class="question"` first. Then, you can get the parts of the text, there are certainly multiple options. Can you provide a link to the web site for me to test? Thanks.

Comment: @Princee thanks, please try out the solution in the updated answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you! I have a question, though. Doesn't `find_by_xpath()` return an element object? How is such a variable type compatible with the `.html` method?

Comment: @Princee glad it worked. `.html` attribute of an element returns an HTML code of an element which is what we are feeding to `lxml.html`.